# Display special page if website server is down. Is there a way to do this without nginx proxy?

Tags: dns, custom-error-pages

I want to display beautiful page (with excuses) to the users if my webserver is down.
How it is possible?

My first idea was to make VM in cloud and to setup nginx there, which will check if webserver is available, and display beautiful error page if it's not.

Is there another way to perform it (without nginx proxy)? (Maybe some magic with dns.. i don't know)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With proxy, when you site is up, all traffic will pass through that proxy. Now, what will you do when the proxy is down ? - While trying to handle one point of failure you just introduce an additional one. Also, you site response time will be lower, and you will pay three times for your traffic (your website, VPS in and VPS out). Hence, proxy idea alone makes little sense.

What you can do is when your site is down, point DNS records for your site to some other location (like your VPS). You will need [DNS provider which supports dynamic updates](http://talkdns.info).

You may also have such DNS-based failover completely as a service - see [dnshat.com](http://dnshat.com), [edgedirector.com](http://edgedirector.com) and lots of others.